# how Anylogic gridCell moveTo

Tags: anylogic

In AniLogic, I've created 144 grid cells using rectangle presentations to represent them. I want to command the agent to move within these cells, but I don't know the exact coordinates of each cell. I've been trying to use "jump to" to skip between cells, but I'm unsure how to proceed in this situation. How can I resolve this?

The location of the initial plane was
f_MoveToCell
(jumpTo(cell.getX(), cell.getY());)

v_initialCell = randomFrom(findAll(cells, c ->  !c.f_isBoarder()));

robot.f_MoveToCell(v_initialCell, false);

You have set it

Cell specifies the initial number of agents at 144

400 - Cell.v_CellHeightAndWidth + Cell.v_CellHeightAndWidth * ( index % 12 )

120 - Cell.v_CellHeightAndWidth + Cell.v_CellHeightAndWidth * ( index / 12 )

The XY coordinates were used to make the simulation appear when it was run

What code should I use to get the plane to the next cell?
I need the correct coordinates to use jump to, but I don't know the coordinates of the next cell